# Casa do Design identity sans serif font identification

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Can anyone help me identify this type from the Casa do Design Matosinhos identity?

Font websites give approximations that are not even similar. I ran it many times but always fail; It looks standard but I still fail to identify it.

[image]

This is the original source https://www.behance.net/gallery/52195599/Casa-do-Design-Identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's some variant of [Helvetica](https://www.myfonts.com/search/helvetica/) (which the rest of the identity your image comes from uses too). Although at that low of a resolution it's hard to make out which exact weight/variant is being used...

Compare the original (top) with the same typed in Helvetica Bold (bottom):

[image]